# Displaying data from my python script on a webpage

Tags: python, html, cgi

My case: 
I want to display the meal plan from my University on my own online "Dashboard". I've written my python script to scrape that data and I get the data I need (plain Text). Now I need to put it on my website but I don't know how to start. On my first searching sessions, I have found something with CGI but I have no clue how to use it:( Is there maybe an even easier way to solve my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the Django, if you don't want to use django, you can edit your output in HTML formate and publish html page, directly.